# Componentes en react

Tags: reactjs

Estoy aprendiendo `react` e hice un ejercicio y me funciono, pero no entiendo muy bien unas partes de los componentes.

```
const Title = (props)=>{
  return <h1>{props.course}</h1>
}
const Parts = (props)=>{
  return <p>{props.part2} {props.exercises1}</p>
}
const Sum=(props)=>{
  return <p>Number of exercises {props.exercises1+props.exercises2+props.exercises3}</p>
}

const App = () => {
  const course = 'Half Stack application development'
  const part1 = 'Fundamentals of React'
  const exercises1 = 10
  const part2 = 'Using props to pass data'
  const exercises2 = 7
  const part3 = 'State of a component'
  const exercises3 = 14

  return (
    <div>
      <Title course={course}/>

      <Parts part2={part1} exercises1={exercises1} />

      <Parts part2={part2} exercises1={exercises2} />

      <Parts part2={part3} exercises1={exercises3} />

      <Sum exercises1={exercises1} exercises2={exercises2} exercises3={exercises3}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Cree 3 componentes pero en el componente `Parts` no entiendo muy bien como funciona la parte del `return` específicamente en el `part2={par1}` ese `part2` lo puedo poner como `part1` o `part3` y funciona pero si pongo un `part4` ya no funciona esto porque sucede?

Gracias.

Comment: En el componente `Parts` puedes pasar la `prop` `part4={part1}`, pero ten en cuenta que la debes recibir con ese identificador,  por ejemplo `return {props.part4}`, ¿ya lo probaste así?

Comment: @g.4 aa osea que en el return de abajo el identificador lo define el return del componente?

Comment: .@Rafael No estoy seguro de cual es tu duda, ¿Puedes actualizar la pregunta con el código que te genera la duda en especifico? El escenario de `part4`, saludos

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que le pasas esto? `<Parts part2={part4} exercises1={exercises3} />` Si es así no te funciona porque o tienes definida la constante part4 y props.part4 será `undefined`.

Comment: Interesante la situación, por algún motivo se está viendo part2 como una variable declarada y que se está redefiniendo para pasar un valor como prop, por eso funciona con part1 y part3, no funciona con part4 como no deve funcionar para cualquier otro nombre que se utilice, de la misma manera no deve funcionar si se utiliza un exercises4. Nunca había visto nada parecido, a la hora de pasar props se declara el valor previamente, no la clave, esta simplemente se pone así sin más. Alomejor esto esta pasando por la foma de crear los componentes etc... Pero no devería pasar, React no es así.